# How to remove file when over quota without root permissions and truncate, dd, mv, cp, and rm fail?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I'm working on a file system where I don't have root permissions and all of the above have failed to allow me to delete a file with the same errors:

```
$ >file1
$ -bash: file1: Disk quota exceeded

$ dd count=1 if=/dev/random of=file1
$ dd: opening `file1': Disk quota exceeded

$ rm file1
$ rm: cannot remove 'file1': Disk quota exceeded

$ cat /dev/null > file1
$ -bash: file1: Disk quota exceeded
```

Also tried this on a buch of files:

```
$ mv file1 f
$ mv: cannot move `file1` to `f`: Disk quota exceeded
```

**edit** 
have now also tried:

```
$ cp /dev/null file1
$ cp: cannot create regular file 'file1': Disk quota exceeded
```

to no avail (same error msg received)

there are a lot of other files I that just give me a permission denied error but I think for some of those it's because I don't have root permissions. Anyways, there are plenty of files for which I do have write permissions so I really just need a way to force those files to be erased. Is there any workaround I can use?

Output of df -s for this filesystem:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
zfs1.local:/volatile  699G  699G     0 100% /nfs/volatile
```

Comment: It won't even let you *open* the file because the disk quota is exceeded? Wow. That looks like a broken filesystem. From what I can tell, your entire mount is basically read-only now. You'll have to ask the relevant system administrator to remove at least one large file for you, or temporarily relieve your quota.

Comment: @allquixotic That's exactly what I'm afraid of :/  But I think you're right

Comment: Can you rename (`mv`) any files? If so, try renaming a bunch of files to single-character names. That might free up enough space in the metadata blocks to let you `rm` a file. If you have enough long file names, you should be able to free up a kilobyte or more. Not sure how much you need free to be able to truncate or delete a file, but it should get you somewhere.

Comment: I tried that in desperation a few hours ago thinking I was clever but sadly it failed as well with the same error.

Comment: What filesystem is this, by the way? Do you know? It may be a bug in the filesystem itself that it has to *use* space to do anything. The answer that Cyrus posted REALLY should have worked, since ZFS is copy on write, and even ZFS allows that to work.

Comment: It's a zfs filesystem which is even more confusing. **edit** added df -s output to question due to formatting issues in comments section

Comment: Is this ZFS on Linux, or is the actual backing store of your ZFS over NFS on Solaris or OpenSolaris of some kind? I saw nfs mentioned in your df output, so that may be complicating things. The problem may be on your client side, or the NFS layer, or even in the ZFS implementation.

Comment: At the moment I couldn't tell you. I bit the bullet and submitted a request to my sysadmin.  I figured if I could solve the problem before 8 am I'd be in the clear. By now I'm certain every developer in my office is wondering what on earth happened.  

I would assume the backing store is over NFS.

Comment: Okay, but make sure not to let them blame this on you. Make it very clear that **this is a filesystem bug** and a fix is needed. You shouldn't be able to get into this situation, no matter what. There must always be a way to reduce the amount of used space on the volume by taking some action.

Comment: Will do. If they share the fix with me I'll post it here

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of the above worked when the quota was 100% full. Fortunately the /tmp was not full so I did:

```
rsync --remove-source-files -azv file1 /tmp
```

and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have recovered the system using the command 'wipe'. Execute wipe on some big file and then try to use the command 'rm'. it will work.

Comment: Can you elaborate at all- why would `wipe` work when `rm` wouldn't?

Comment: As allquixotic commented in the question, ZFS is a copy-on-write filesystem, so a file deletion actually needs slightly more space on disk before a file is deleted. It has to write the metadata before it remove a file, whereas the command **wipe** actually removes the file content in the way it cannot be recovered. It does not requires extra space in disk. So the condition "Disk quota exceeded" will not affect **wipe**.